# PHP switch & array

Tags: php, arrays, email

I have a bit of code and limited exposure to PHP and codeignitor it's built in, I need to adapt but unsure which is the best way to go about it, currently when someone orders off the sites it's based of a single custmer_id an order email gets sent to our customer and a BCC gets sent to the admin, these are set in a config file under the 2 setting variables below, this site now has 4 delivery addresses, and they need a confirmation email set to a specific email address based on the order delivery address from the individual customer ID.

so if I have customer ID's of SD100, SD100A, SD100B and SD100D each with it's own email (not stored in a database) how would I go about writing a switch to hard code the email addresses for the array to use for the recipient email address, then having a fall back of $settings[ 'customer_email_confirmation' ] = $settings[ 'email' ]; if they add another delivery address, but without and email?

Custom_Config.php settings:

```
$settings[ 'customer_email_confirmation' ] = $settings[ 'email' ];
$settings[ 'customer_email_confirmation_bcc' ] = 'admin@site.com;
```

cart.php controller I have the following code:

```
function _send_email_to_admin_to_confirm_order( $cart, $user, $items ) {
    $company_name = $this->get_setting( 'company_name' );

    $msg = "Order ID: ".$cart[ 'order_id' ]."<br/>";
    $msg.= "Customer ID: ".$cart[ 'customer_id' ]."<br/>";
    $msg.= "Delivery address: ".$user[ 'delivery_address_name' ]."<br/>";
    $msg.= "Date: ".$cart[ 'creation_date' ]."<br/><br/>";

    $msg.= $this->_email_list_items( $items );

    mymail( array(
        'recipient' => $this->get_setting( 'admin_email_confirmation' ),
        'bcc' => $this->get_setting( 'admin_email_confirmation_bcc' ),
        'subject' => $company_name.' - new order',
        'from' => 'no-reply@site.co.uk',
        'msg' => $msg,
        'error_label' => 'Sending email has failed: '
    ) );
}
```

Thanks in advance

Regards

Mal